# Python truth interpretation

Tags: python, boolean

I am taking a Python course, the following is an example code snippet; I understand it:

```
# A program that reads a sequence of numbers
# and counts how many numbers are even and how many are odd.
# The program terminates when zero is entered.

odd_numbers = 0
even_numbers = 0

# Read the first number.
number = int(input("Enter a number or type 0 to stop: "))

# 0 terminates execution.
while number != 0:
    # Check if the number is odd.
    if number % 2 == 1:
        # Increase the odd_numbers counter.
        odd_numbers += 1
    else:
        # Increase the even_numbers counter.
        even_numbers += 1
    # Read the next number.
    number = int(input("Enter a number or type 0 to stop: "))

# Print results.
print("Odd numbers count:", odd_numbers)
print("Even numbers count:", even_numbers)
```

Then this portion appears in the lesson:

> Try to recall how Python interprets the truth of a condition, and note that these two forms are equivalent:
>
> `while number != 0:` and `while number:`.

I subbed in the `while number:` in the code above and the code functions correctly.

I don't understand WHY `while number:` means `while number !=0`

Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another user has already said, the reason that this has the same result is because 0 is interpreted as False in the context of the while loop, while anything other than 0 is interpreted as True.

Therefore, `while number` and `while number != 0` will both be True while the number is anything other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with truthy and falsy values, better explained in this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/).

Basically, when you use a `while` or `if` operator, you are evaluating that value in a boolean context, `0` is considered a falsy value, so it evaluates to `False`.

Comment: kinda important to add that _any_ other integer evaluates to `True`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are saying. Basically, since Zero evaluates as 'false' I don't need to specify that '!=0' for the condition to be 'true' because any other value (other than Zero) for the variable 'number' will be evaluated as a 'true' condition and will trigger the loop. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

in Python **False** and **0** are sort of the same thing, same for **True** and **1**. as @Matiis mentioned in the comment above.

```
while number
```

or any thing looks like this, means **while** this **variable** neither equals **False**, **Zero** nor **None**, the same applies for **if**

```
if number
```

Answer (score 0):

while expect a boolean
and bool(0) returns False

```
bool(0)
False

bool(10)
True
```

and

```
0 != 0
False

10 != 0
True
```

That the reason why

```
while number != 0
```

is the same that

```
while number
```